# Mysql 'group by' clause does not give error

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

My Table name is '**product**' which contains the following column.

```
1. id
2. name
3. description
4. Price
```

While running following SQL query this does not give me an error.

```
select name, sum(Price) from product group by Description;
```

while running this query on PostgreSQL It gives me the error.

According to 'group by' clause column name in select clause should be part of a group by condition.

Hence according to above, SQL query name should be part of a group by condition.

Comment: dear mysql is user friendly..it doesn't consider its as error while postgresql & sql server both must have to follow group by function rule of using aggregate function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL this behaviour is configurable through [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) sql mode setting:

> Reject queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined by) GROUP BY columns.
>
> As of MySQL 5.7.5, the default SQL mode includes ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.
>   (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and
>   ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. For a description of
>   pre-5.7.5 behavior, see the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual.)

In your MySQL ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql mode is apparently not set. If you would like MySQL to reject the query, then you need to enable this behaviour. Actually, I would encourage everybody to make sure that this sql mode is enabled - unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: I think you are correct. Also I have gone through the following link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

you should write query like this

you should write only **group by column name and aggregate function** in select column name.

```
select Description, sum(Price) from product group by Description;
```

if you want to get name you should write query like this

you should add name in group by.

```
select name, sum(Price) from product group by name,Description;
```

and if you want to group by only Description then you can write query like this.

```
select max(name), sum(Price) from product group by Description;
```

if name are same you can use `min` or `max` function to get name or **simply add in group by**